# Parenthesized equalities: meaning of parenthesis before equal sign, e.g. $ \frac{n}{q}+\frac1{2q}\left(=\frac{n+1}{q}-\frac{1}{2q}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

What does the parentheses before the equal sign mean?

[image]

I’ve also never seen an inequality be used in an equation before like this. I’ve searched online but found no help. However, if anyone can be so kind as to send me a link to a text that can help, or take it up themselves to explain I’d be so grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Just delete the paren's, e.g. $\,a-b\,(= a+2b\, -\, b)$ means $\,a-b = a+2b\, -\, b.\,$ It's a parenthetical remark, as in natural language prose.

Comment: I don't like that at all. Can I ask what book that is from?

Comment: @Jorge: It looks fine to me. I think there could be more space before the opening parenthesis, but I don't think that's what you're complaining about!

Comment: @Jorge it’s “ An introduction to number theory” by Harold Stark

Comment: As @Bill Dubuque says, it's a [parenthetical remark](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/grammar/dashes-parentheses-and-quotation-marks/uses-of-parentheses). However, the editor and/or proofreader should have inserted several empty horizontal spaces before the left parenthesis. In fact, I suspect their absence may have been caused by an unqualified (for mathematics editing/proofing) editor, since it's hard for me to imagine anyone remotely knowledgeable about mathematics who would write it this way to begin with.

Comment: @TonyK I think the vast majority of people will be able to understand it considerably faster without the parenthesis

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, really. I didn’t know it was something so simple. Now it makes sense thank you

Comment: @Dave The preferred amount of amount of spacing is a matter of taste. Some prefer more - some less. That someone prefers less does not imply that they are  "unqualified or .... not remotely knowledgeable about mathematics".

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Perhaps, but to me having no space easily allows for an unintended interpretation by someone who may have initially thought the equals sign was a typo, even if only temporarily, and a mathematically astute writer would be aware of an unnecessary reader roadblock such as this. I suspect Halmos would consider this roadblock as something that belongs to Section 16 -- Use Symbols Correctly -- in his article [*How to write mathematics*](https://entropiesschool.sciencesconf.org/data/How_to_Write_Mathematics.pdf).

Comment: @Dave Again, it's a matter of opinion / taste / style - which often has little correlation to mathematical knowledge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means:

> Therefore, either $$\frac nq \le \alpha \le \frac nq + \frac1{2q}$$ (and by the way, notice that the right-hand side of this inequality is the same as $\frac{n+1}{q}-\frac{1}{2q}$), or ...

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from Troposphere's good answer, I think he means:

> Therefore, either $$\color{brown}{\frac nq \le \alpha \le \frac nq + \frac1{2q} \qquad  (\text{notice the right-hand side equals } \frac{n+1}{q}-\frac{1}{2q})}$$
> or